# Insert character at every occurrence of another character in a string javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string `3-5,10-15,20` and I want to insert `p` before every number. I wanted to just find each '-' and ',' and insert a 'p' after each one, and then one at the beginning.
Looping over it requires manipulating the string you're looping over, which wasn't working quite well for me. I feel like this is such a simple task, but I'm getting stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

The final result should look like `p3-p5,p10-p15,p20`.
This is what I tried:

```
input = `p${input}`;
for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
   if (input[i] === '-' || input[i] === ',') {
    input = `${input.slice(0, i + 1)}p${input.slice(i + 1)}`;
   }
}
```

Comment: ok , so where  exactly are you implementing this?

Comment: please add the wanted result and your try.

Comment: Edited answer for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could search for digits and replace the digits with added value.

```js
var string = '3-5,10-15,20',
    result = string.replace(/\d+/g, 'p$&');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can you explain the second argument in `replace`?

Comment: it takes the string for each replacement and `$&` is the matched value, all connected digits in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex to match the `-` and the `,` character and replace them using a group.

```js
const input = '3-5,10-15,20';

console.log(input.replace(/([-,])/g, "$1p"));
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Esp. the $1?

Comment: the first digits have no `'p'`.

Comment: @pianoman102 The regex `[-,]` matches a `-` or `,` this character is placed in group 1 by surrounding it with parentheses. `$1` will replace the match with the contents of group 1 the `p` behind `$1` adds a `p` behind the match.

Comment: `$1` is a special replacement pattern in javascript `String.replace()` that inserts the first parenthesized submatch string in this case `[,-]`

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Description